# ListView setAdapter keeps returning NullPointerException

Tags: java, android, listview

I am trying to search addresses using google maps api and fill a ListView with the results. The idea is to use an EditText and every time a key is pressed use the new text to cause a search for matching addresses and fill the ListView with the new results. I have checked and the id for the ListView in findViewById is correct.

```
public class SearchActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener{

//    List that will be used to show the search results
    List<Address> listItems;
//    Adapter that will be used to fill the ListView in layout file
    ArrayAdapter<Address> adapter;



         @Override
                protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);

                    adapter=new ArrayAdapter<Address>(this,
                            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                            listItems);


                    final EditText search_txt=(EditText) findViewById(R.id.search_edittxt);
                    search_txt.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onKey(View view, int i, KeyEvent keyEvent) {

                        String searchTerms=search_txt.getText().toString();
                        if(searchTerms.length()>0)
                            UpdateResults(searchTerms);

                        return false;
                    }
                });
            }

         public void UpdateResults(String address)
            {

               Geocoder geocoder=new Geocoder(this);
               try {
                      listItems=geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5);
               } catch (IOException e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
               }
               if(!listItems.isEmpty()) {
                   ListView searchResultsList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.search_result_list);
                   searchResultsList.setAdapter(adapter);
                   adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
            }
```

And the xml layout file is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.heycabs.heycabs.SearchActivity"
    tools:showIn="@layout/activity_search">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:id="@+id/topLayout"
        >
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="260dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:id="@+id/search_edittxt"
            />
        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_search_category_default"
            />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/topLayout"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/topLayout">

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/search_result_list"
            android:drawSelectorOnTop="false">
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

But every time, `searchResultsList.setAdapter(adapter)` is causing a NullPointerException. Here is the stack trace.

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                             at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)
at android.widget.ListView.setAdapter(ListView.java:466)
at com.heycabs.heycabs.SearchActivity.UpdateResults(SearchActivity.java:82)
at com.heycabs.heycabs.SearchActivity$1.onKey(SearchActivity.java:65)
at android.view.View.dispatchKeyEvent(View.java:7239)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchKeyEvent(ViewGroup.java:1376)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1937)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1410)
at android.app.Activity.dispatchKeyEvent(Activity.java:2388)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatActivity.java:533)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.dispatchKeyEvent(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:254)
at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.dispatchKeyEvent(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:53)
at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchKeyEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1864)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEventPostIme(ViewRootImpl.java:4175)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverKeyEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4093)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3574)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4849)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4809)
at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewRootHandler.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:3384)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5409)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:606)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Uhm, show the xml please. Something is amiss here. And we're gonna find what :)

Comment: Just did. Appreciate the help.

Comment: Base on this:`at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getCount(ArrayAdapter.java:330)` have you checked to see if the item count is <= 0? That's the first line in the stack trace.

Comment: Just updated the code to add that check in "UpdateResults" method. Still getting the same error on the same line. Which is now inside the "UpdateResults" method

Comment: Have you thought of using a "CustomAdapter" instead of an ArrayAdapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you've not initialized listItems. Do this

```
List<Address> listItems = new ArrayList<Address>();
```

and don't assign new reference to listItems in UpdateResults method. So instead of this:

```
listItems=geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5);
```

do this:

```
listItems.clear();
listItems.addAll(geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5));
```

Comment: If i change that line to "List<Address> listItems = new List<Address>();" android studio says that List is abstract and cannot be instantiated. And gives me like 20 more methods to override which i don't know anything about.

Comment: I did as you said, and now in "listItems.add(geocoder.getFromLocationName(address, 5));"
its telling me "add (android.location.Address) in List cannot be applied to (java.util.List<android.location.Address>" syntax error that is.

Comment: @RehanYousaf `.addAll()` instead of `.add()`

Comment: @RehanYousaf and you don't need to set the adapter again and again as you just did.

Comment: after replacing .add() with .addAll() the app has stopped crashing finally. But now i am faced with another problem. The list is getting filled with a lot of garbage instead of proper addresses, Like so. "...CityName="Paris", CountryName="France"..." Can you suggest any way to refine that into something along the lines of, "... Paris, France..."

Comment: You'll need a list_item layout for that. I suggest you to go through some listview tutorial like this: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: @RehanYousaf If your original question has been answered, please consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Sorry. I couldn't figure out how to accept the answer.